# Using RPush (APNs) with Rails to push to specific user

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Background: a Rails app, on Heroku with Postgres database. Using UIWebView to make it 'native' in iOS. When trying to include push notifications, there are gems such as [APNS](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS), [RPush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush) and [Grocer](https://github.com/grocer/grocer), among others.

However they need the device token to be able to send the push notification to, and that needs to be linked up to the correct user id so that we send the notification to the right person. Such as when using a chat feature.

As far as I can see these gems are used more for larger scale pushing of notifications to all users. To be able to send them to specific users at specific points, I need the token to correspond to users.

As far as I can see there isn't documentation for this. I was thinking one of the easiest ways to do this was if Swift could talk directly to the Postgres database, and see who is logged in on the app and then assign the token to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing I would say ahead of time, though this might be obvious, you will have to store a user's device token in a model on your rails app. Here's how I usually do it:

1. Create a Device model with a token (string) field that belongs to a User
2. Create an API endpoint that allows you to store that device_token like `POST /user/1234/devices.json {token: "...xxx..."}`
3. In your iPhone app, register a user to receive push notifications which will then give you the device token
4. Push that device token to your API endpoint :)
5. When you want to send a push notification to that specific user you would do something (using Rpush, though you could modify this for any of them) like:

   ```
   @user.devices.each do |device|
     n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
     n.app = your_rpush_app
     n.device_token = device.token
     n.alert = "Here's a pretty sweeeeeet message! Eh?"
     n.data = {}
     n.save!
   end
   ```

This will cause a message to get sent to each one of that users devices! You could obviously adapt this to only use one device, allow for multiple operating systems, etc. But, you get the idea :)